# Cannot use Jackson/JAXB after Spring upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

The new Spring Boot 3.x upgrade (which also means an upgrade of Java to Java 17) has changed the namespaces from "javax" to "jakarta".

I am getting an exception when I run my application because it is still referencing the "javax" namespace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124)
```

Looking at the stack, it references "javax" instead of "jakarta"

[image]

As far as I can tell 2.16.0 is the highest version that `jackson-module.jaxb` goes to.

How can I use Jackson if it's not compatible with the Spring upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Jakarta version of JAXB, as used by Spring Boot 3, you should not use that `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` module, you should use the [`jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations) module instead.

The *jakarta-xmlbind* in the module name refers to the Jakarta EE 9+ variant of JAXB, using the `jakarta.xml.bind` namespace instead of the `javax.xml.bind` namespace of Java EE 8 and older.

See also on the [FasterXML jackson-modules-base repository](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base), which refers to the *jaxb* module as *"Old" (`java.xml.bind`) annotations* and the *jakarta-xmlbind* module as *New "Jakarta" (`jakarta.xml.bind`)*.

The reason these modules coexist is because not everyone has upgraded to libraries or tools using Jakarta EE 9+ libraries, so Jackson wants to support both the old and the new namespace simultaneously, and that requires separate libraries/modules.

In short:

1. Remove `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` from your dependencies
2. Add `jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations` to your dependencies
3. Replace references to `JaxbAnnotationModule` (if any) with `JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule`
4. Replace references to `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` (if any) with `JakartaXmlBindAnnotationIntrospector`
5. Use `gradle dependencies` or `mvn dependency:tree` (or with `./gradlew` or `./mvnw`) to find out if anything else is pulling in `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations`. You'll likely need to replace or upgrade those dependencies as well.

   For example, as pointed out in the comments by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981788/alex), you might have `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` on your classpath, which will need to be replaced with `com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs:jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider`.

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same error.

Comment: You also need to remove any reference to `JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` and instead use `JakartaXmlBindAnnotationIntrospector`, and you need to remove the _jaxb_ variant of the module from your classpath.

Comment: I am not using any introspector classes

Comment: @OliverWatkins It is right there in your stacktrace (`com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector`). If you configure your object mapper to load modules automatically, it will discover and try to load it automatically if it is still on your classpath (and if you still get this error with that stacktrace, then it **is** still on your classpath). If you get this error with a different stacktrace, then something else is also still trying to use JAXB 2.x or lower annotations.

Comment: yes. but that is being called from jackson.databind.ObjectMapper I'm not directly calling that part of the stack trace. I am not sure what you mean about removing the jaxb variant

Comment: You still have the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` library on your classpath. Remove it from your dependencies, or if you haven't listed it explicitly find out how it is pulled in as a dependency and exclude it (`mvn dependency:tree` or `gradlew dependencies`), or double-check if that is a dependency that also needs to be updated or replaced.

Comment: in my case `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` is pulled in by `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.16.0` , so as @MarkRotteveel said, do a `mvn dependency:tree` or `gradlew dependencies` to see who is pulling that dependency

Comment: @Alex Yes, for example that one should be replaced by the `com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs:jackson-jakarta-rs-json-provider`

Answer (score 1):

Jackson can support both the `jakarta.xml.bind` and the `javax.xml.bind` namespaces in the same project, and use the corresponding namespace, module and introspector, depending on which namespace is used in your data classes, i.e. classes containing the `@XmlElement` and similar annotations.

For supporting both, you can include both `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` and `jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations` into your project. An example of the relevant sections from `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You may also need some non-Jackson-specific Jakarta packages, not sure if you need all of the listed here in your particular project:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-bom</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Then you create an `XmlMapper` like this (Kotlin code):

```kotlin
    val xmlMapper: XmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
            .addModule(JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule())
            .addModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .addModule(JaxbAnnotationModule())
            .addModule(KotlinModule.Builder().build())
            .defaultUseWrapper(false)
            .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            .build()
```

And use the created `XmlMapper` like this:

```kotlin
    val mappedDocument: YourDocumentClass =
       xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, YourDocumentClass::class.java)

    // ...

    val xmlString: String =
        xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(mappedDocument)
```