# how to resolve BeanCreationException telegrambot and spring-boot 3.2.1

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot on spring boot 3.2.1 that will be connected to the MySQL database, but I get an exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1232) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.example.demodb.DemoDbApplication.main(DemoDbApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule.setupModule(JaxbAnnotationModule.java:98) ~[jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:879) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:1081) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1165) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.<init>(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:26) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonIntegration.<clinit>(JacksonIntegration.java:18) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.lambda$determineJsonFormatMapper$6(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:803) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.determineJsonFormatMapper(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.createSessionFactoryBuilder(DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.java:26) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersis
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.1
 

com.example
demoDb
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
demoDb
demoDb

<java.version>21</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my app.properies

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

I changed the spring boot version to 3.1.4 and everything works but I want to work on the new version

Comment: Running a dependency tree in both cases: the one working and the one not should give you a good idea of the classpath issue you're encountering. Maybe also check Spring changelog for updates to apply and/or use Spring BOM if it's not already the case.

Comment: I bet that this`javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement`. is the problem..

Comment: Spring Boot 3 uses the JakartaEE 9 version of JAXB, which use the `jakarta.xml.bind` package namespace, not `javax.xml.bind`. The `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector` that is referenced in your stacktrace shouldn't be on the classpath. This seems similar to [Cannot use Jackson/JAXB after Spring upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639313/cannot-use-jackson-jaxb-after-spring-upgrade). You'll need to check what is pulling in the wrong library (jackson-module-jaxb-annotations instead of jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations), and fix your dependencies.